# It seems I can vote for my own answer, and get rep for it.

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I voted for my own answer, and I got a message saying I can't do that.
So I tried again, but this time navigated away before the message popped up... and now it seems I got 10+ rep for that vote.

If I navigate back to the page later, it appears to remove the vote and reduce my rep count.

The question is here:
[What is the PS3 Jailbreak?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8216/what-is-the-ps3-jailbreak/8233#8233)

I don't intend to repeat the exercise... and I will go back and remove the vote later, but I've left as is for now to demonstrate.

Comment: I see one upvote at the moment, which happened to be me.

Comment: My rep was 33, it's now at 43. It went to 43 when I when I voted my answer up... let me go back to the question and see does it take back that rep now like it did before.

Comment: Did you up vote after you read this, or before?

Comment: You may want to go to your user page on gaming.SE (click the envelope icon by your name up top), click Reputation, select a date range, and see where all of your 43 rep is coming from. You should be able to see if the rep is coming from the "What is the PS3 Jailbreak?" question or elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I see 10 rep for that question. But WillfulWizard said he did an upvote on that question - so apparently that's where my rep came from. So my question to WillfulWizard is, did he upvote after he saw this bug report, or before. Maybe it was all just a co-incidence and he upvoted while I was messin with the upvote. So I'm very interested to know when he cast his upvote.

Comment: @Mark. Definitely before I saw this post on meta. Then I saw this and wondered at the coincidence.